# Substracting multiple DFs in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 1 big DF (hundreds of million records) and I wish to subtract this
DF from multiple smaller DF(few millions) which are actually multiple tables I read from database, what will be better performance wise:

1) Running union on all the smaller DF's and then running except

2) Running multiple except on the various dataframes

BR,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first option as there is likely less shuffling and UNION is a simple operation in Spark terms. Stands to reason, latter is just adding partitions somewhere.

EXCEPT is implemented as a LEFT ANTI JOIN. At the physical execution level, this latter is executed as an aggregation involving shuffling. Doing this once overall is better than doing this a number of times.

An .explain could reveal to what extent Catalyst takes this into account.

As is always the case, an excellent read here https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/apache-spark-2.4.0-features-except-all-intersect-all/read